# How can the variance of my normal-distributed data equals to zero? Something must be wrong

Tags: r, statistics

I need to calculate heritability for "Mean_radius" in my data. I use package sommer and lme4 in R to calculate the variance, and so I can compare their results. I set "mean_radius" as fixed effect, and "Isolate" (individuals), "Set" (the date to collect data of mean_radius) and "Replicate" as random effect. But I get weird results...

Q1: The variance for the replicates are always zero, though the three replicates for each Isolates are not the same values. I don't understand how the variance for replicates can be zero? I think it must have something wrong, but I can find it out.

Q2: why the two package using the same model result in different numbers for variance, e.g. variance for Isolate?

Can somebody help me out? I have been trying to find the problem for two days...

Codes:

`Y<- read.table("Book1.txt", head = TRUE) 
head(Y)
attach(Y)`

## for lme4 package

`Radius_varcomp <- lmer(Mean_Radius~(1|Isolate) +(1|Set)+(1|Isolate:Set) + (1|Replicate))`

Result:

`Groups      Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Isolate:Set (Intercept) 9.719e-05 0.0098585
 Isolate     (Intercept) 4.552e-07 0.0006747
 Set         (Intercept) 5.157e-06 0.0022709
 Replicate   (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.0000000
 Residual                4.851e-06 0.0022025`

## for sommer package

`ans2 <- mmer(Mean_Radius~1, random=~Isolate+Set+Isolate:Set +Replicate,data=Y)
summary(ans2)$varcomp`

Result:
`> summary(ans2)$varcomp
                                         VarComp    VarCompSE       Zratio Constraint
Isolate.Mean_Radius-Mean_Radius     0.000000e+00 2.988808e-25 0.000000e+00   Positive
Set.Mean_Radius-Mean_Radius         1.478642e-03 1.013914e-21 1.458350e+18   Positive
Isolate:Set.Mean_Radius-Mean_Radius 3.308684e+06 2.839923e-22 1.165061e+28   Positive
Replicate.Mean_Radius-Mean_Radius   0.000000e+00 1.262430e-08 0.000000e+00   Positive
units.Mean_Radius-Mean_Radius       4.689617e-06 2.023829e-07 2.317200e+01   Positive`

The data can be accessed from here *http://www.filedropper.com/book1_3*

Comment: google "singular fit".  Can you please put the data somewhere I don't have to provide my e-mail address and agree to terms and conditions before I download it?

Comment: I update the link for downloading data.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have read some information about "singular fit" in here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models From what I understand, it seems my model is overfitted. But from the data collection and the experimental design, I don't think I can delete the interaction level of `Set` and `Isolate`. Also, it still doesn't explain to me why the variation in my replicates are zero. Could you please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close/migrate to CrossValidated. You don't have enough replicates to reliably compute the among-replicate variation: see [here](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/4187) for an example/explanation.